# Random number resets every time click event handle executes

Tags: c#

Hello I am currently trying to make a guessing game with windows form app in c#. I can not figure out how to make it so my random number only generates one time. For example every time I click my guess button (as shown in guessButton_Click) it generates a different random number. I just want the random number to be generated just once during this code run. How can I accomplish this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public partial class randomNumberForm : Form
{
    Random ranNum = new Random();
    int userGuess = 0;
    int numberOfGuesses = 0;

    public randomNumberForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void randomNumberForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    public void guessButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int randomNumber = ranNum.Next(101) + 1;
        if (int.TryParse(inputTextBox.Text, out userGuess))
        {
            if (userGuess < randomNumber)
            {
                answerLabel.Text = "Too low, try again.";
                numberOfGuesses++;
                guessLabel.Text = numberOfGuesses.ToString();
            }
            else if (userGuess > randomNumber)
            {
                answerLabel.Text = "Too high, try again.";
                numberOfGuesses++;
                guessLabel.Text = numberOfGuesses.ToString();
            }
            else if (userGuess == randomNumber)
            {
                answerLabel.Text = "You guessed the right number!";
                numberOfGuesses++;
                guessLabel.Text = numberOfGuesses.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid integer.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe, put `int randomNumber = ranNum.Next(101) + 1;` inside a different `Button.Click` event, used to create a new game when the previous is guessed right. When the code in `guessButton` determines that the guess is corrent, ask to press the second Button to start a new game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  must have a global variable.

see the example below

```js
public partial class randomNumberForm : Form
{
    Random ranNum = new Random();
    int userGuess = 0;
    int numberOfGuesses = 0;
    int? randomNumber;

    public randomNumberForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void randomNumberForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    public void guessButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!randomNumber.HasValue) // first time run 
            randomNumber = ranNum.Next(101) + 1;
        if (int.TryParse(inputTextBox.Text, out userGuess))
        {
            if (userGuess < randomNumber)
            {
                answerLabel.Text = "Too low, try again.";
                numberOfGuesses++;
                guessLabel.Text = numberOfGuesses.ToString();
            }
            else if (userGuess > randomNumber)
            {
                answerLabel.Text = "Too high, try again.";
                numberOfGuesses++;
                guessLabel.Text = numberOfGuesses.ToString();
            }
            else if (userGuess == randomNumber)
            {
                answerLabel.Text = "You guessed the right number!";
                numberOfGuesses++;
                guessLabel.Text = numberOfGuesses.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid integer.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: This helped a ton. I just added what you put as an else statement and the if statement is the code I wrote. I am very new to c# and I have been trying to figure this out for hours. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Look at where you've placed the line `int randomNumber = ranNum.Next(101) + 1;` - it's the very first thing your button click event does, and it will run every single time the button is clicked.

Declare your `randomNumber` variable at the top of the class as a private int. This will make it a class variable which is only accessible from within the class itself.

Move your line of code `randomNumber = ranNum.Next(101) + 1;` into the `randomNumberForm_Load` function. This will populate the `randomNumber` variable on the form load event.